# Windows - how to disable/test disk cache

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, cache

I have some problems with my WD5000AAKX disk and i think that faulty RAM cache could be the reason.
Western Digital diagnostic tool reports that everything is OK.

Is there any way how to disable read cache on disk in Windows 8? 
Or is there any software which is able to test every memory location in my HDD cache?

Comment: What makes you thing the cache on the disk is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I found way to disable a read cache on windows with hdparm.

1. Download hdparm with cygwin from [this site](https://sites.google.com/site/disablehddapm/home?pli=1)
2. Run it with parameter: `hdparm -A 0 hda`